# Using Count aggregate clause within a join

Tags: sql

I have two table whose structure is as follows
**Table authors**
last_name,first_name,author_id(pk)(foreign key refferenced by Titleauthor)

**Table TitleAuthor**
title_id(pk)
author_id(the refferencing foreign key),
Title

I want to retireive authors with two or more titles, list their name and the number of books published.

However when i try a join and a count,i get the error that  "group function is not allowed here".I am a begginner in sql,how do i achieve this?Here is my code

```
 SELECT last_name,first_name
FROM authors a
JOIN titleauthor ta
ON ta.author_id= a.author_id
WHERE COUNT(ta.author_id)>2
ORDER BY author_lname;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `where` with `having` after adding a `group by` clause.

```
SELECT a.last_name, a.first_name
FROM authors a
JOIN titleauthor ta
ON ta.author_id= a.author_id
GROUP BY a.last_name, a.first_name
HAVING COUNT(ta.author_id)>2
ORDER BY a.last_name, a.first_name;
```